# json_decode load more with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

i am looking for a very simple way to add a load more button to my json results, heres my code

```
        // GET JSON DATA FOR TIMELINE
        $UserTimeline = 'MYSITE/TimelineQuery.php?id='.$UserPageIDNum.'';
        $TimelineContent = file_get_contents($UserTimeline);
        $TimelineJson = json_decode($TimelineContent, true);



        //OPEN FOREACH TIMELINE POSTS
        foreach ($TimelineJson['data'] as $TimelineData)
            {

               if(isset($TimelineData['post']['TrackID'])){
               echo $$TimelineData['post']['TrackID'];
              }

             }
```

What would be the simplest way to list the results to 5 and then press a load more button to load another 5 results and so on...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the code as shown here, your call to the PHP-routine would have an additional parameter:  the starting-point, and possibly the maximum number of lines that should be returned.  The server is to return that "slice" of lines.

The client remembers what starting-line it asked for previously, and how many lines it's asking for.  The server *should* be designed to include line-numbers in its response.  When a response comes back, the client merges the data into what data it already knows about, *and* notices if the maximum number of lines was returned.  (If not, presumably the end-of-data has been reached.)

As usual, be very mindful of the fact that *"this sort of thing has been done before, many times."*  Look, on GitHub and elsewhere, for any **existing** piece of code, on both the client and the server side, that you can ... so to speak ... "steal."  :-)